# Как получить имя домена из ссылки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная:

```
var url = "https://domain.com/?a=111&b=222&c=333";
```

Как в переменной оставить только domain.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться классом [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

И взять свойство [`hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hostname)

```js
var url = "https://domain.com/?a=111&b=222&c=333";

var u = new URL(url);

console.log(u.hostname);
```